# Understanding Devel::Leak

Tags: perl, debugging, memory-leaks, profiling

Below is a piece of code I am using and its output.

```
my $handle;
my $enterCount = Devel::Leak::NoteSV($handle);
print "$date entry $enterCount";
<<<< my piece of code >>>
my $leaveCount = Devel::Leak::CheckSV($handle);
print "$date exit $leaveCount";
```

output:

```
1) 
Mon 11/10 02:34:55 entry 383852
Mon 11/10 02:35:03 exit 486726

2) 
Mon 11/10 04:00:31 entry 383852
Mon 11/10 04:00:39 exit 493216

3)
Mon 11/10 04:05:15 entry 383852
Mon 11/10 04:05:23 exit 493927
```

Every time I run my script the `$enterCount` value is same whereas the `$leavecount` values keeps on increasing. What dose this signify? Does it represent memory leak ? What exactly does it show?

Comment: Umm ... probably?  Wouldn't you have to show the rest of your code for people to definitely say one way or the other?  Even if this is a pretty much a duplicate question I still think it is a good one since there's no real "canonical" answer ... but see links below.

Answer (score 2):

You could check these SO references from [@ether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559958/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-develleak):

- [Finding a Perl memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663498/finding-a-perl-memory-leak)
- [Are there any tools for finding memory leaks in my Perl program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295385/are-there-any-tools-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-my-perl-program)
- [Common Perl memory/reference leak patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223721/common-perl-memory-reference-leak-patterns)

jkeroes on Github has a list of [resources](https://gist.github.com/jkeroes/3763713#file-perl-memory-modules) on perl memory leaks.

[`Devel::Gladiator`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Gladiator) is good for getting an overview of what is going on - you could probably modify your code to fit with the POD's Synopsis example.